# Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I'm dealing with dates and times in Rails and Postgres and running into this issue:

The database is in UTC.

The user sets a time-zone of choice in the Rails app, but it's only to be used when getting the users local time for comparing times.

User stores a time, say March 17, 2012, 7pm. I don't want timezone conversions or the timezone to be stored. I just want that date and time saved. That way if the user changed their time zone, It would still show March 17, 2012, 7pm.

I only use the users specified time zone to get records 'before' or 'after' the current time in the users local time zone.

I'm currently using 'timestamp without time zone' but when I retrieve the records, rails (?) converts them to the time zone in the app, which I don't want.

```
Appointment.first.time
 => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 19:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Because the records in the database seem to come out as UTC, my hack is to take the current time, remove the time zone with 'Date.strptime(str, "%m/%d/%Y")' and then do my query with that:

```
.where("time >= ?", date_start)
```

It seems like there must be an easier way to just ignore time zones all around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 399, accepted):

Postgres has two different timestamp data types:

- [**`timestamp with time zone`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), short name: **`timestamptz`**
- [**`timestamp without time zone`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), short name: **`timestamp`**

`timestamptz` is the *preferred* type in the date/time family, literally. It has `typispreferred` set in [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html), which can be relevant:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

#### Internal storage and [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)

Internally, timestamps occupy **8 bytes** of storage on disk and in RAM. It is an integer value representing the count of microseconds from the Postgres epoch, 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Postgres also has built-in knowledge of the commonly used [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) counting seconds from the UNIX epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and uses that in functions [`to_timestamp(double precision)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) or [`EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamptz)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

[The source code:](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/datatype_2timestamp_8h_source.html)

```
* Timestamps, as well as the h/m/s fields of intervals, are stored as
* int64 values with units of microseconds.  (Once upon a time they were  
* double values with units of seconds.)
```

And:

```
/* Julian-date equivalents of Day 0 in Unix and Postgres reckoning */  
#define UNIX_EPOCH_JDATE        2440588 /* == date2j(1970, 1, 1) */  
#define POSTGRES_EPOCH_JDATE    2451545 /* == date2j(2000, 1, 1) */
```

The microsecond resolution translates to a maximum of 6 fractional digits for seconds.

#### `timestamp`

For **`timestamp`** no time zone is provided explicitly. Postgres *ignores* any time zone modifier added to input literals!

Nothing is shifted for display. With everything happening in the same time zone this is fine. For a different time zone the *meaning* changes, but *value* and *display* stay the same.

#### `timestamptz`

Handling of **`timestamptz`** is subtly different. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5714)

> For `timestamp with time zone`, the internally stored value is **always in UTC** (Universal Coordinated Time ...)

Bold emphasis mine. The **time zone itself is never stored**. It is an input modifier used to compute the according UTC timestamp, which is stored. Or an output decorator according to the `timezone` setting of the current session. For input literals without offset, the current `timezone` setting is assumed. All computations are done with UTC timestamp values.

If more than one time zone may be involved, or if there can be any doubt or misunderstanding, go with `timestamptz`. Best for most use cases.

Clients like psql or pgAdmin or any application communicating via [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq.html) (like Ruby with the `pg` gem) are presented with the offset for the *current* time zone or according to a *given* time zone (see below). It's always the same point in time, only the display format varies. As [the manual puts it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES):

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
> are converted to local time in the zone specified by the [`TimeZone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE)
> configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

Example in psql:

```
db=# SELECT timestamptz '2012-03-05 20:00+03';
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2012-03-05 18:00:00+01
```

What happened here?
The input literal with (arbitrary) time zone offset `+03` is just another way to format the UTC timestamp `2012-03-05 17:00:00`. The result of the query is *displayed* for the current time zone setting, "Vienna/Austria" in my test, with an offset `+01` during winter and `+02` during summer time ("daylight saving time", DST). So `2012-03-05 18:00:00+01` for the "winter" time.

Postgres only retains the *value*. Just like with a decimal number: `numeric '003.4'` or `numeric '+3.4'` - either results in the exact same internal value.

#### `AT TIME ZONE`

To project timestamp values to a specific time zone, use the [**`AT TIME ZONE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct. `timestamptz` is converted to `timestamp` and vice versa.

To get UTC `2012-03-05 17:00:00+0` as `timestamptz`:

```
SELECT timestamp '2012-03-05 17:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00 UTC'
```

To display the same point in time as EST `timestamp` (Eastern Standard Time):

```
SELECT timestamp '2012-03-05 17:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'EST'
```

That's right, `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` **twice**. The first interprets the `timestamp` value as (given) UTC timestamp returning the type `timestamptz`. The second converts `timestamptz` to `timestamp` as seen on a wall clock in the given time zone 'EST' at this point in time.

#### Examples

```sql
SELECT ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
FROM  (
   VALUES
      (1, timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00+0')
    , (2, timestamptz '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1')
    , (3, timestamptz '2012-03-05 17:00:00 UTC')
    , (4, timestamp   '2012-03-05 11:00:00' AT TIME ZONE '+6') 
    , (5, timestamp   '2012-03-05 17:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') 
    , (6, timestamp   '2012-03-05 07:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Hawaii')  -- ①
    , (7, timestamptz '2012-03-05 07:00:00 US/Hawaii')                  -- ①
    , (8, timestamp   '2012-03-05 07:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'HST')        -- ①
    , (9, timestamp   '2012-03-05 18:00:00+1')  -- ② loaded footgun!
      ) t(id, ts);
```

Returns 8 (or 9) *identical* rows with a `timestamptz` column representing UTC timestamp `2012-03-05 17:00:00`. The 9th row sort of happens to work in my time zone, but is an evil trap.

① Rows 6 - 8 with time zone **name** and time zone **abbreviation** for Hawaii time are subject to DST (daylight saving time) and might differ, though not for the given winter times. A time zone name like `'US/Hawaii'` is aware of DST rules and all historic shifts, while an abbreviation like `HST` is just a dumb code for a fixed offset. You may need to append a different abbreviation for summer / standard time. The *name* correctly adjusts *any* timestamp at any point in time (as recorded in the underlying library). An *abbreviation* is cheap, but needs to be the right one for the given timestamp:

- [Time zone names with identical properties yield different result when applied to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042506/time-zone-names-with-identical-properties-yield-different-result-when-applied-to)

<sub>*Daylight Saving Time is not among the brightest ideas humanity ever came up with.*</sub>

② Row 9, marked as *loaded footgun* happens to work for me. For `timestamp [without time zone]` input, [any time zone offset is ignored](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#id-1.5.7.13.18.6)! Only the bare timestamp is used. The value is then coerced to `timestamptz` in the example to match the column type. For this step, the `timezone` setting of the current session is assumed, which happens to be Europe/Vienna for me and matches `+1`. But not in other cases, resulting in a different value. In short: Don't cast `timestamptz` literals to `timestamp` or you lose the time zone offset.

### Your questions

> User stores a time, say March 17, 2012, 7pm. I don't want timezone
> conversions or the timezone to be stored.

Time zone itself is never stored. Use one of the methods above to enter a UTC timestamp.

> I only use the users specified time zone to get records 'before' or
> 'after' the current time in the users local time zone.

You can use one query for all clients in different time zones.
For absolute global time:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE time_col > (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time
```

For time according to the local clock:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE time_col > now()::time
```

Not tired of background information, yet? [There is more in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: Minor detail, but I think timestamps are stored internally as the number of microseconds since 2000-01-01 - see [date/time datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html) section of the manual. My own inspections of the source seem to confirm it. Strange to use a different origin for the epoch!

Comment: @harmic As for different epoch… Actually not so strange. This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) lists two dozen epochs used by various computer systems. While the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is common, it is not the only one.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter This is a *great* answer, except for one serious flaw. As harmic commented, Postgres does *not* use Unix time. According to [the doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES): (a) The epoch is 2001-01-01 rather than Unix’ 1970-01-01, and (b) While Unix time has a resolution of whole seconds, Postgres keeps fractions of seconds. The number of fractional digits depends on the compile time option: 0 to 6 when eight-byte integer storage (default) is used, or from 0 to 10 when floating-point storage (deprecated) is used.

Comment: **CORRECTION:** On my earlier comment, I incorrectly cited the Postgres epoch as 2001. Actually it is **2000**.

Comment: Is there a way to have the `AT TIME ZONE` statement for `SELECT p.*` like queries when the timestamp column is one of the columns of the table `p`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211953/sql-at-time-zone-query-wide-and-with-a-select-all-columns-tablename-exp

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, isn't epcoh 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z?
From doc: "epoch  date, timestamp  1970-01-01 00:00:00+00 (Unix system time zero)"
epoch  date, timestamp  1970-01-01 00:00:00+00 (Unix system time zero)

Comment: @ALZ: There are different "epochs" floating around. I clarified above.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, sorry, but I didn't got it. In docs I see 1970. When PG will use 2000?

Comment: @ALZ: Internal storage is based on the Postgres epoch 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: how about store and transmit UTC only, display according to user's time zone ?

Comment: I think the answer could be more concise, maybe because the answer is  agnostic instead emphasizing the rails part

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal in UTC by default:

In `config/application.rb`, add:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

Then, if you store the current user timezone name is `current_user.timezone` you can say.

```
post.created_at.in_time_zone(current_user.timezone)
```

`current_user.timezone` should be a valid timezone name, otherwise you will get `ArgumentError: Invalid Timezone`, see [full list](https://gist.github.com/Dorian/e1c273500183206363856601338f6a5a).

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if Erwin's answer contains a solution of the problem (still it contains tons of useful info), but I have a

### shorter solution:

*(at least shorter for reading)*

`.where("created_at > ?", (YOUR_DATE_IN_THE_TIMEZONE).iso8601)`

### Why all the mess happens

When you try to implement something like `.where("created_at > ?", YOUR_DATE_IN_THE_TIMEZONE)` Rails steps in and converts the time to server time (most likely UTC) to convert your date to timestamp (timestamp without timezone format). That's why all the dancing with `in_time_zone` and around is senseless.

### Why iso8601 works

When you call `iso8601` your date is converted into string which Rails can't "brake" and has to pass to Postgres as it is.

***Don't forget to upvote!***

Answer (score 0):

I had similar puzzle plus timestamp precision in my Angular/Typescript/Node API/PostgreSQL environment, here is [complete answer and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67152719/5063031)